# Can't add my function to the Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell

So I pulled this program from another website so it's not mine.

```
Function InteriorColor(CellColor As Range)
     Application.Volatile True
    InteriorColor = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

And I added it to the VBA in excel yet I get #NAME? error, I made sure that I set it to Enable All Macros, so I don't really understand the error.

I used this

```
=InteriorColor(AQ113)
```

In the cell

Comment: Copy the function to any module.

Comment: where have you put the function

Comment: [this](http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm) might help you.

Comment: Okay so I put it in a module, and I still get the error, I refreshed it. I don't really understand why I am getting the error, I put it in the same Workbook as the one I want to use it in.

Comment: What is the error message you get after moving the code to module ?

Comment: Same #NAME? Now that its in the module it doesn't appear in the VBA. If that matters.

Comment: Make sure you have mentioned the correct formula name. #Name occurs when formula is not found.
If the formula resides in any module there is no reason why you get this error.

Comment: Exactly Santosh, I just don't understand. Is there a quick way I can post screen shots?

Comment: You may upload the file on dropbox and give the link which will be helpful to identify the issue.

Comment: I got it in the module, I can't upload the file due to privacy laws but now I get a #VALUE! error, I am using the call above is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, I suspect you have put the code under `ThisWorkbook` in the editor.

You should right click the project -> Insert -> Module, then paste the code in the new module

[image]

Comment: Just in case OP misunderstands what a `module` means. So, just to make it more explicit

Comment: It will be more helpful if you add images as well.

Comment: I got it in the Module but now as I said I get a #VALUE! error

Comment: I used =InteriorColor(AQ110) and on that cell it has the color as red, so it should return a 3.